# Remove default focus outline and change to different color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'd like to remove the blue outline from my contact box (the color clashes with the other colors on my page). I tried a bunch of things suggested on SO questions to no avail and get the same result on Chrome and Firefox.

Here's what I tried:

```
input:focus, button:focus, textarea:focus, textarea:focus, input:active, button:active, textarea:active, input:active, input, textarea, button {
  outline-style: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
  border: 1px solid #17a2b8; /* Turquoise color */
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a `box-shadow` style applied on focus.

[image]

add this code to remove it:

```
.form-control:focus {
   box-shadow:none;
}
```

You may add `!important` depending on your CSS order:

Comment: We should add that you shouldn't remove it for accessibility reasons, you should change it to suit your site's style but it should remain visible.